# I'd like to get used to using the word 'way' can I use whichever I want among them?

Tags: sentence-construction

yesterday I played basketball by myself and a foreign girl asked me if she could join me. I liked teaching her. it was something that I've dreamed of experiencing, playing basketball with a girl. And Jina, you could learn from a guy you like.

> 1. It can be a strategic way of making him have a good feeling about you.
> 2. It can be a strategic way (that) you make him have a good feeling about you.
> 3. It can be a strategic way to make him have a good feeling about you.

I'd like to get used to using the word 'way' can I use whichever I want among them?

Comment: First and third are fine, but the second seems clumsy. Not wrong grammatically; just awkward compared to 1&2.  Oh, by the way, you can't "make" anybody have a "good feeling about you". You can hope to _make a good impression_, hoping thereby to _encourage_ them to feel good about you.

Comment: how about this sentence: It can be a strategic way to let him with a good impression of you.

Comment: and how about this sentence ; smile alot. it is a good way that you can make a lot of friends.

Comment: "let him with" s/b _leave him with_. otherwise it's good.  As for "smile alot..."  it s/b _Smile a lot..._, and I still think the "way that you can make" is clumsy.  _...way to make..._ is simpler, more straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the sentence with "way" is meant to be the next sentence in the little paragraph you wrote, then you could say:

> It could be a good/great way to get him to like you.

or

> It could be a good/great way of getting him to like you.

"Strategic" is grammatically okay here, but "good" or "great" sounds much more natural.

Also, it sounds more natural to stick with "could" than to change to "can."

Also, "get someone to like you" sounds more natural than "make someone have a good feeling about you."

Otherwise, your sentences 1 and 3 are grammatically correct, as shown by the structure of the two sentences I suggest. The only difference between them is the use of the to-infinitive versus the use of the -ing form.